# Código sencillo para obtener datos de mysql

Tags: php, json, api

Que opinan de este código, que mejorarian o cambiarían (usa el principio de consulta del lado cliente así sólo devuelve lo solicitado)

```
<?php 
  $ejecutar = new conexcion;
  $host_db = "localhost";
  $user_db = $_GET["user"];
  $pass_db = $_GET["pass"];
  $db_name = $_GET["db"];

  try 
    {
      $conexcion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_db.';dbname='.$db_name, $user_db, $pass_db);
    }
  catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
      print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "
      ";
      die();
    }
  $con =null;

  $datas = $_GET["cadena"];
  $parte = explode(" ",$datas);
  switch ($parte[0]) 
  {
    case 'SELECT':
       $ejecutar->rps($datas, $conexcion);
      break;

    case 'INSERT':
       $ejecutar->wps($datas, $conexcion);
      break;

    default:
      # code...
      break;
  } 

  Class conexcion
  {
    public function rps($sqlq, $conexcion)
    {
      $result = $conexcion->query($sqlq);
      if ($result->fetchColumn()>0)
      {
        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
          $data[] = $row;
        }
        echo( json_encode($data) );
      }
      $result = null;
      $conexcion=null; 
    }

    public function wps($sqlq, $conexcion)
    {
      if ($result = $conexcion->query($sqlq)) 
      {
      echo ("Todo Correcto");  
      }
      else {
        echo ("Error");  
      }
      $result = null;
      $conexcion=null; 
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: el primer comentario que le hago a tu código es que no deberías pasar por GET los valores de la conexión pues es información sensible

Comment: no es para amarga su trabajo, pero hoy en dia se utilizar los framework que facilita realizar las operaciones mysql, si quiere puede estudia el **elounque de laravel**, entre las funciones esta el with que me permite traer datos foranies sin la necesidad de hace un join, y le cuento que tiene 2000 linea de codigo

Comment: Yo haría varios cambios comenzando por separar la clase de la función, así podrás implementarla en cualquier otro archivo php, por otro lado usa post para pasar la información, y usa get solo cuando pases un solo parámetro, al separarlo todo podrás reutilizar el código. Saludos

Comment: El uso de Get es por prueba, manejo laravel y graphql, este es solo un experimento para hacer algo facil de entender, quiero dejar de usar frameworks

Comment: Mi inquietud es, ¿Es seguro, será posible una inyección sql y otro tipo de ataque? Claro cambiando los Get por post

Comment: Tu código **NO** es seguro. Para protegerte de la inyección SQL debes usar **consultas preparadas**.